# Hibernate jackson when does serialization take place

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson

I am learning Spring, Hibernate, Jackson & AngularJS.

I am trying to understand the life cycle between application and database when using Spring, Hibernate, Jackson & AngularJS.  Because I think I am getting confused between Jackson & Java Serialization / Deserialization.... do they do the same thing?  They do different things at different times.

Below is a simple diagram of Hiberante ORM architecture how I understand it when reading the docs.  Hibernate uses the config from your applicationContext or config.xml to create a single SessionFactory and share it across the application. SessionFactory creates session which contains methods such as save(), saveOrUpdate(), delete()...etc.

[image]

Hibernate has 3 states of action.

- Transient state: the object not associated with database.
- Persistent state: the object is mapped with database identity.
- Detached state: when persistent state is complete when the session is closed, object becomes detached....

[image]

So if I have a controller that inserts a book in to database

```
// create book entry
@RequestMapping(path="/booklist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Book> newBook(@RequestBody @Valid Book book, BindingResult result){

    if(result.hasErrors()){

        //------
        //  Some error code handling
        //------

        book.setErrorObjBuilder(errorObjBuilder);

        return new ResponseEntity<Book>( book, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);

    }else{
        bookDao.saveOrUpdate(book);


        return new ResponseEntity<Book>(book, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
};
```

1. The book object gets passed in to `newBook(@RequestBody @Valid Book book)` is it already serialized (java.io.Serializable)?  or serialization takes place at `bookDao.saveOrUpdate(book)`
2. Does the serialization takes place before the book is persistent object?
3. In above example when does Jackson serialize or deserialize take place?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all It is not recommended to call your DAO logic in the controller, you better have a service which calls the DAO logic to separate the concerns and be able to keep each business logic in a transaction.

> The book object gets passed in to newBook(@RequestBody @Valid Book
> book) is it already serialized (java.io.Serializable)? or
> serialization takes place at bookDao.saveOrUpdate(book)

This is not serialization, this is the desirialzation, serialization convert java object to serialization format (like json) and deserialization does the opposite, the deserialization takes place after the request is mapped by the servlet mapper and before triggering the api, that is why if there is a problem with the deserialization the api will not be triggered.

> Does the serialization takes place before the book is persistent
>
> object?

Hibernate is an ORM, which maps java object model to relational model, so what will be persisted is a jave model, deserialization happens on the controller level

> In above example when does Jackson serialize or deserialize take
> place?

I already answered the deserialzation part , for serialization it takes place after your controller returns the result in case you have @ResponseBody on your api method or your controller is a RestController

Comment: thanks for your answer.....`not recommended to call your DAO logic in the controller` thanks for pointing this out...May I ask why?  I have seen a lot of examples where Service seems to be just another wrapper of Dao.  Do you know of any good links that has a good Service Implementation?  thanks

Comment: if my answer answers your question please accept it

Comment: @EricHuang Service is not a wrapper for DAO, we tend to make controller and DAO layers as thin as possible in order to keep our concerns separated, Dao layer should not contain and business logic, controller layer is just the interface of your system, if you put the DAO directly in the controller you will increase the coupling hence when the DAO changes you will havet o consider changing your controller logic, also service represents the business logic so it helps you manage your transaction , a failure in one business logic leads to roll all that logic back

Comment: I know its not a wrapper but I have seen enough examples where in the controller they will go something like this `bookService.create(book);`   inside of the BookService create() method calles bookDao `bookDao.saveOrUpdate(book);`  which makes service just another layer that repeats Dao...

Comment: @EricHuang In your service you will have your business logic not just triggering the Dao, this business logic should be included in one transaction, in addition if something change in the business logic you will only need to change that specific logic since the relation between the controller and service is already defined ( using abstraction), maybe u come across a case were service is just calling DAO but it is possible this will change and a logic will be added later right?